# Create undirected graph by boost graph same as the input

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I want to create the graph as following, first column is vertex, other's are adjacency vertex

- 1 2 3 4 7
- 2 1 3 4
- 3 1 2 4
- 4 1 2 3 5
- 5 4 6 7 8
- 6 5 7 8
- 7 1 5 6 8
- 8 5 6 7

I add the edges into the graph like this

```
using MinCutG = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;

MinCutG graph;
std::vector<std::vector<int> > input{ {1,2,3,4,7}, {2,1,3,4}, {3,1,2,4},
            {4,1,2,3,5}, {5,4,6,7,8}, {6,5,7,8}, {7,1,5,6,8}, {8,5,6,7}};
for(auto const &data : input){
    auto begin = std::begin(data);
    auto end = std::end(data);
    if(begin != end){
        auto const Vertex = *begin;
        ++begin;
        while(begin != end){
            boost::add_edge(Vertex, *begin, graph);        
            ++begin;
        }
    }
}
```

print the graph

```
template<typename Graph>
void print_adjacent_vertex(Graph const &g)
{
    for (auto vertex = vertices(g); vertex.first != vertex.second; ++vertex.first){
        std::cout << *vertex.first << " is connected with ";
        for (auto neighbour = adjacent_vertices(*vertex.first, g);
             neighbour.first != neighbour.second; ++neighbour.first){
            std::cout << *neighbour.first << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

I expect the outputshould same as the input, but it is not
The results are

- 1 is connected with 2 3 4 7 2 3 4 7
- 2 is connected with 1 1 3 4 3 4
- 3 is connected with 1 2 1 2 4 4
- 4 is connected with 1 2 3 1 2 3 5 5
- 5 is connected with 4 4 6 7 8 6 7 8
- 6 is connected with 5 5 7 8 7 8
- 7 is connected with 1 5 6 1 5 6 8 8
- 8 is connected with 5 6 7 5 6 7

my expected results

- 1 is connected with 2 3 4 7
- 2 is connected with 1 3 4
- 3 is connected with 1 2 4
- 4 is connected with 1 2 3 5
- 5 is connected with 4 6 7 8
- 6 is connected with 6 5 7 8
- 7 is connected with 7 1 5 6 8
- 8 is connected with 8 5 6 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, using `setS` for the `OutEdgeList` template parameter will disable parallel edges, resulting in the desired output.

The first template parameter to [`boost::adjacency_list`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html) is `OutEdgeList` and it controls certain graph behaviors, such as allowing or disallowing parallel edges.  In the case of undirected `MinCutG` graph, `vecS` is used as the `OutEdgeList` which will enable parallel edges.  For example, if an undirected graph supported parallel edges, then with:

```cpp
add_edge(1, 2, graph); // Vertex 1 and 2 are adjacent to one another via edge A.
add_edge(2, 1, graph); // Vertex 1 and 2 are adjacent to one another via edge B,
                       // which is parallel to edge A.
```

The [`adjacent_vertices()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/AdjacencyGraph.html) for vertex `1` will contain vertex `2` twice, once for each edge (`A` and `B`).

As noted in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/graph/doc/using_adjacency_list.html#sec%3achoosing-graph-type), parallel edges can be disabled by using `setS` or `hash_setS` selectors for the `OutEdgeList`.  For example, change:

```cpp
using MinCutG = boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::vecS, // OutEdgeList with parallel edges
  boost::vecS,
  boost::undirectedS>;
```

to:

```cpp
using MinCutG = boost::adjacency_list<
  boost::setS, // OutEdgeList with no parallel edges
  boost::vecS,
  boost::undirectedS>;
```

---

Here is an [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1add78029aece4c) using the original code and only changing the `OutEdgeList` from `vecS` to `setS`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

template<typename Graph>
void print_adjacent_vertex(Graph const &g)
{
    for (auto vertex = vertices(g); vertex.first != vertex.second; 
         ++vertex.first){
        std::cout << *vertex.first << " is connected with ";
        for (auto neighbour = adjacent_vertices(*vertex.first, g);
             neighbour.first != neighbour.second; ++neighbour.first){
            std::cout << *neighbour.first << " ";
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    using MinCutG = boost::adjacency_list<
        boost::setS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS>;

    MinCutG graph;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > input
    {
        {1,2,3,4,7},
        {2,1,3,4},
        {3,1,2,4},
        {4,1,2,3,5},
        {5,4,6,7,8},
        {6,5,7,8},
        {7,1,5,6,8},
        {8,5,6,7}
    };

    for(auto const &data : input){
        auto begin = std::begin(data);
        auto end = std::end(data);
        if(begin != end){
            auto const Vertex = *begin;
            ++begin;
            while(begin != end){
                boost::add_edge(Vertex, *begin, graph);        
                ++begin;
            }
        }
    }
    print_adjacent_vertex(graph);
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
0 is connected with 
1 is connected with 2 3 4 7 
2 is connected with 1 3 4 
3 is connected with 1 2 4 
4 is connected with 1 2 3 5 
5 is connected with 4 6 7 8 
6 is connected with 5 7 8 
7 is connected with 1 5 6 8 
8 is connected with 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tanner explained, you essentially add every edge twice, first as (a,b) and later as (b,a). One but rather expensive way to avoid this is to use `setS` as the template parameter which controls edges container. And this is what Tanner suggested in his answer.

Alternative is to check whether edge exists before adding it. It means the line

```
boost::add_edge(Vertex, *begin, graph);
```

should be replaced with

```
if (! edge(Vertex, *begin, graph).second ) //edge does not exist yet
    boost::add_edge(Vertex, *begin, graph);
```

In most situations this code is likely to be faster and to consume less memory.